# How to word wrap in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, editor, ssms

How do I enable word wrap for SQL Server Management Studio 2008's query editor?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Just enable it through the options.

- Tools
- Options
- Text Editor
- All Languages
- Settings - Check Word Wrap

Comment: It is very good answer, but I prefer the option of adding "toggle word wrap" button and not change the editor default.

Comment: Same process for SSMS 18, except following All Languages > General > Word Wrap.

Answer (score 21):

Tools - Options - Text Editor - Transact-SQL - Word wrap

Answer (score 13):

you can add it to your tool bar.

1. tool bar(right click)
2. customize
3. commands tab
4. choose the toolbar you want to add it to (2nd radio button)
5. press 'add command'
6. from categories 'edit' choose 'toggle word wrap'
7. press 'ok'

Answer (score 7):

Goto:

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Text Editor
4. All Languages
5. General
6. Word wrap

Comment: Over the years various upgrades(both major & minor) have been done on SSMS giving developers more control over the functionalities with each release. The above  answer has been posted with reference to SSMS vs 18.2 wherein several bug fixes have been made in the area "SSMS options"

Comment: I just updated from SSMS 18 to SSMS 19, and I had to turn this on despite the prompt I received for copying settings over.